# How to rewrite the following?(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I am trying to write the following

```
double sum_res = 0.0;
double yhat = 0;
double res = 0;
int n = 0;

for(int i=0;i<x.Count;i++)
{
    yhat = inter + (slp*x[i]);
    res  = yhat - y[i];
    n++;              
}
```

using lambda but somehow not able to get it work(compile time error)

```
Enumerable.Range(0, x.Count).Select(i =>
                {
                    yhat = inter + (slp * x[i]);
                    res = yhat - y[i];
                    sum_res += res * res;
                    n++;
                });
```

**Error: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.**

Help needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Aggregate` instead of `Select` since it more closely models what you're really trying to do.

```
        double sum_res = Enumerable.Range(0, x.Count).Aggregate(0.0, (sum, i) =>
        {
            yhat = inter + (slp * x[i]);
            res = yhat - y[i];
            n++;
            return sum + res * res;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

the error you are getting is pretty good--LINQ has no idea what you are going to return from your lambda. . . Sam shows how the compiler can figure out what you are returning by explicitly returning something of a known type.

In the future, think about how the compiler would be able to discern what it is you are attempting to return from your expression. That can give you a clue about how to form your expression in a way that the compiler can work out.

If your expression is unambiguous, you don't need to explicitly state a return, otherwise you need to help the compiler as Sam illustrates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are incrementing `n` but that really doesn't belong. I would go for something like this.

```
double sum_res = Enumerable.Range(0, x.Count).Aggregate(0.0, (sum, i) => 
    sum + Math.Pow((inter + (slp * x[i])) - y[i]), 2.0))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda body has no return statement, hence the error. `Select` method takes `Func<TSource, TResult>` lambda as a parameter, which is a function taking something of the same type as the collection and returning something else. You must have a return statement in order for this to work.